# How best to implement the polling consumer pattern in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, long-polling, ajax-polling

**Background**

Back in May I reported an issue on WebKit regarding a [memory retention issue](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=39825). It looks as though the problem could be due to the Web Inspector itself, but I'm not convinced yet.

**Problem**

A problem surfaced whereby my JavaScript application implements a "[Polling Consumer](http://www.eaipatterns.com/PollingConsumer.html)" pattern for obtaining data as it becomes available. The problem is that memory is being retained and grows throughout the day. The JavaScript logic goes like this:

1. Get the data and call me back
2. When I'm called back process the data and
   then perform step 1

Is this a reasonable way of implementing a polling consumer in JavaScript? Incidentally I'm using jQuery's ajax function which of course may have its own problems. In addition I'm using a jQuery proxy as the success handler so I would have thought that retention through scope should not be an issue. I have also observed the problem without using proxies. Some code:

```
FidsDataController.prototype.getFids = function() {
  var self = this;
  $.ajax({
...
    success: function(data) {
      // Do some processing
      // Call back in a short while...
      setTimeout($.proxy(self.getFids, self), 100);
    },
...
  });
);
```

Comment: Do you just want to poll the server for data?

Comment: I need to poll the server continuously as per "polling consumer". The idea is that the server blocks until a request becomes available. The client either receives data when it becomes available or times out if the server dies.

Answer (score 1):

You have only one copy of `getFids`, which is good, but every time it gets called you are creating two new functions: one for the success handler and one from the `$.proxy` call.  These two functions are not unique per call.  Put them in reusable variables and you'll spare lots of extra function creation, which should lower your memory leak potential by a lot.

Example where we make proxied versions of each function once per object, in the constructor.  Repeated calls will not generate more functions:

```
function FidsDataController() {
  // ...constructor...


  // Proxy these functions just once from the prototype
  this.getFids = $.proxy(this.getFids, this);
  this._getFids_success = $.proxy(this._getFids_success, this);
}

FidsDataController.prototype.getFids = function() {
  var self = this;
  $.ajax({
    success: this._getFids_success;
  });
};

FidsDataController.prototype._getFids_success = function(data) {
  // processing of data
  setTimeout(this.getFids, 100);
};
```

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you're saying... can you provide an example in code? Also, I'm not trying to lower my memory leak; I'm trying to eliminate it!

Comment: Thanks for the example. As stated before though, I don't see my memory leak going away. I should also add that my problems occurred without using proxies too. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Well, I don't think there's a lot you can do to eliminate leaks entirely in JavaScript.  You could try moving the `100` and the object literal passed to the `$.ajax` function into static properties as well, if it might help.  There's probably something else, though, that's not clear from this example.

Comment: So let me then ask you another way, if you were to implement a polling consumer, would you do it in the way that I've done it?

Comment: You should look into "Comet" techniques like long-poll and Web Sockets.